# Is there a way to export a page with CSS/images/etc using relative paths?

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I work on a very large enterprise web application - and I created a prototype HTML page that is very simple - it is just a list of CSS and JS includes with very little markup. However, it contains a total of 57 CSS includes and 271 javascript includes (crazy right??)

In production these CSS/JS files will be minified and combined in various ways, but for dev purposes I am not going to bother.

The HTML is being served by a simple apache HTTP server and I am hitting it with a URL like this: `http://localhost/demo.html` and I share this link to others but you must be behind the firewall to access it.

I would like to package up this one HTML file with all referenced JS and CSS files into a ZIP file and share this with others so that all one would need to do is unzip and directly open the HTML file.

I have 2 problems:

- The CSS files reference images using URLs like this `url(/path/to/image.png)` which are not relative, so if you unzip and view the HTML these links will be broken
- There are literally thousands of other JS/CSS files/images that are also in these same folders that the demo doesn't use, so just zipping up the entire folder will result in a very bloated zip file

Anyway -

I create these types of demos on a regular basis, is there some easy way to create a ZIP that will:

1. Have updated CSS files that use relative URLs instead
2. Only include the JS/CSS that this html references, plus only those images which the specific CSS files reference as well

If I could do this without a bunch of manual work, if it could be automatic somehow, that would be so awesome!

As an example, one CSS file might have the following path and file name.

`/ui/demoapp/css/theme.css`

In this CSS file you'll find many image references like this one:

`url(/ui/common/img/background.png)`

I believe for this to work the relative image path should look like this:

`url(../../common/img/background.png)`

Comment: In your text editor, try replacing '/ui/' with '../../'?

Comment: @Torr3nt That is what I do now, which involves a lot of manual find & replace - there could be various levels of nesting and doing a simple replace `/ui/` with `../../` on all CSS files would not work in all situations.

Comment: Doing a simple search&replace in your editor would have taken less time and effort than asking on SO.  This question is bordering on not really belonging on SO (re: you would require a specialized application to do what you're asking for).  [Compass extensions](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions) *could* do some of what you're asking for, but it is going to require extensive configuring/converting by hand.

Comment: @cimmanon You may be right about the amount of manual effort (i.e. going through 57 CSS files to perform find&replace, and manually copying files into a zip file) - however as I noted, this is something that I do often so I am looking for an automated way. It wouldn't necessarily need to be a "specialized application" since this is a general problem and doesn't rely on the specifics of the content of the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer my own question because I have solved the problem for my own purposes. There are 2 options that I have found useful:

1. Modern browsers have a "Save Page As..." option under the File menu, or in Chrome on the one menu. This, however does not always work properly when the page is generated by javascript
2. I created my own custom application that can parse out all of the CSS/Javascript resources and transform the CSS references to relative URLs; however, this is not really a good answer for others.

If anyone else is aware of a commonly available utility or something like that which is better than using the browser built in "Save page as..." option - feel free to post another answer.